# Docker is running but get error saying demon is not running

Tags: docker

I'm really new to docker. I have installed docker on my windows 10 laptop.
Then I started docker service. Please refer below screenshots.
[image]

However it shows docker running icon of docker shows it is false.
[image]

This is out put I got in power shell opened as Admin mode.
[image]
 Please support me to bring to docker working status.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#start-docker-for-windows

Comment: Its not work..@I